# How to Apply Pivot on CrossTab With Multiple Header Rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, header, pivot

I have data in the format below:
[Excel-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmDti.jpg)

I want to transform it in below format:
[Excel-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV4pX.jpg)

Any possibilities?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @jeffreyweir I am using Excel-2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called a Nested Unpivot. Because you've got have Excel 2016, you can use the new functionality under the 'Get and Transform' tab to do this really easily. It was previously a separate add-in called PowerQuery, and is now bulk standard in Excel.(In previous versions, you can download the free Microsoft "PowerQuery" addin that was the forerunner for this.)

There's many excellent walkthroughs on the internet showing this exact type of activity. Google "PowerQuery" and "Nested Unpivot", and you'll get lots of tutorials showing how to do this exact thing, including these great examples from Bob Phillips and Ken Puls:

https://wessexbi.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/unpivot-nested-headings-with-power-query/

https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/09/24/un-pivoting-with-subcategories-in-power-query/

If you want further great examples of PowerQuery in action, try googling with "Mike Girvin" or "ExcelIsFun" and you should see like a zillion excellent tutorials on PowerQuery. Try "ExcelCampus" too, as Jon has great tutorials, as does "Chandoo". Also replace PowerQuery with "Get and Transform" and repeat those same searches.

PowerQuery is simple to learn, and lets you do stuff just by "muddling through" that would otherwise take a year or more to learn if you wanted to pick up VBA.

It acts like a user-friendly macro recorder, only unlike the macro recorder it spits out reusable code that doesn't have hard coded references in it, meaning all you need to do his hit Refresh.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jeffreyweir!
Your explanation solved my problem.
Thanks again!